# Delphi INI readstring limitation

Tags: delphi, limit, ini

I'm storing my application's settings in an INI file. I read that there is a limitation of 2kb for a binary entry so I encoded the binary into a string and stored the value as string (writestring). When checking the file, it seems that all the string was stored as expected.

When trying to read it back, it seems that only 2047 characters were read so when decoding it back to a stream, it fails.

Apparently it seems there is a 2kb limitation for string as well but I was wondering if that is that or maybe I did something wrong. If there's such a limitation, any idea how can I bypass it?

Thanks

EDIT:
silly me, I went to system.inifiles and it says in the code

```
function TIniFile.ReadString(const Section, Ident, Default: string): string;
var
  Buffer: array[0..2047] of Char; <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
begin

  SetString(Result, Buffer, GetPrivateProfileString(MarshaledString(Section),
    MarshaledString(Ident), MarshaledString(Default), Buffer, Length(Buffer),
    MarshaledString(FFileName)));
end;
```

Comment: Which delphi version?

Comment: Delphi xe though it might be related to INI in general

Comment: Using the `TMemIniFile`, there is no such limitation.

Comment: FYI [TCustomIniFile.WriteBinaryStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.IniFiles.TCustomIniFile.WriteBinaryStream) did exactly what you are doing, just use it with TMemIniFile or with your inherited class

Comment: Forget INI files at all, they are old and slow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is easy.

Extend `TInifile` and insert your own version of `ReadString`.

```
TMyIniFile = class(TInifile)
      function ReadString(const Section, Ident, Default: string): string; override;
end;

function TMyIniFile.ReadString(const Section, Ident, Default: string): string;
var
  Buffer: array[0..largenumber] of Char;
begin                                
  SetString(Result, Buffer, GetPrivateProfileString(MarshaledString(Section),
    MarshaledString(Ident), MarshaledString(Default), Buffer, Length(Buffer),
    MarshaledString(FFileName)));
end;
```

Comment: `TMemIniFile` is a far better idea. Avoid using these terrible deprecated MS APIs.

Comment: @Amos, the core terrible idea is to store binary data into INI.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Can you please tell why? Do you think [TCustomIniFile.WriteBinaryStream](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/System.IniFiles.TCustomIniFile.WriteBinaryStream) is wrong and needs to be removed?

Comment: @SirRufo, this is against core advantage of quick and easy configuration format, see [paragraphs 3 and 4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970651.aspx).

Comment: @FreeConsulting It just depends on the size of the binary data and not binary data at all. If it's ok to store a 200 char string into ini why it is against all rules to store binary data which string representation is also a 200 char string?

Comment: @SirRufo, there are neither rules nor guidelines, you are free to design solutions as inefficient as you want. For example trying to store binary data in text configuration files invites this kind of problem no-one can fix w/o special software.

Comment: @FreeConsulting Binary data always needs special software to decode it, regardless its storage format or storage kind. And hex representation is well known. So I cannot see any disadvantage as long as you get the job done. And I do not propagate an ini-file as the one and only solution but as one valid solution from many others

Comment: @SirRufo, the presence of this given Q indicates some usage anomaly and potential problem. Just like storing JPEGs to registry, pretty possible, but causes Q to be posted at SO.

Comment: @FreeConsulting These problems (with some limitations) are well known every day around us. But we are developers and we can go around these limitations as the OP does (maybe not the best way to rely on the Windows API). I had no problem to implement a class inherited from TCustomIniFile that will store the data into a sqlite database. But that would not keep me away from knowing about the limitation of this implementation.

Comment: @SirRufo, not the best way to store binary data into text format designed to be easy and convenient (for users, not a developer). OP is struggling against design limitation.

Comment: it's better to replace "FFileName" with "FileName", because "FFileName" is private var in base class